# Opengl Vertex Array Objects

Tags: opengl, vao

Are OpenGL's Vertex Array Objects stored in VRam?

What I'm really asking: If I load a model, using Assimp for example, then read the vertex and indice data into Vertex Array Objects; will I be duplicating data in Ram, or copying it to the GPU?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There seems to be a lack of understanding of OpenGL terminology here.

You cannot read "vertex and indice data" into [Vertex Array Objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object). They don't actually *store* the data; the arrays of data are stored in [buffer objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object). VAOs only *reference* them. VAOs describe how the data in those buffers is formatted so that OpenGL can understand what they mean.

If you are asking about [client-side vertex arrays](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Client-Side_Vertex_Arrays) (note the lack of the word "object", though you can use client-side vertex arrays with VAOs), then by definition they are not stored on the GPU. The "client" of client-side vertex arrays is the user's code. IE: memory you allocated, own, and manage.

If you're asking about the use of [buffer objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object), yes, buffer object storage resides on the "server" (ie: memory owned by the OpenGL implementation). Whether it's actually physically on the GPU at any particular point in time is not something you can determine. But after you call `glBufferData`, `glBufferSubData`, or other such functions that update buffer objects, the server has copied that data.

Comment: Yes there is a lack of understanding about terminology. I've just starting to look at openGL. I'm glad you understood what I was asking though. I was wondering if by allocating Buffer Objects and populating them with data I already had in the Assimp Scene struct, that I would be duplicating data and wasting my time.

Comment: @Kronos25: You'll be duplicating data, but not "wasting time". Runtime performance is what you're after, so getting the data onto the GPU is important in achieving that. Besides, you should *delete* your scene struct after you're done uploading it.