# any function can instead the GetData in VertexBuffer on platforms with OpenGL ES?

Tags: android, opengl-es, xna-4.0, monogame

When I run a game with monogame for Android from wp, it works:

```
    public void InitBuffers()
    {
        meshVertices = new VertexData[meshVertexBuffer.VertexCount];
        meshVertexBuffer.GetData<VertexData>(meshVertices);

        meshIndices = new short[meshIndexBuffer.IndexCount];
        meshIndexBuffer.GetData<short>(meshIndices);

        vertices = new VertexData[meshVertices.Count() * maxAmountOfInstances];
        indices = new short[meshIndices.Count() * maxAmountOfInstances];
    }
```

meshVertexBuffer is from a model which have a vertexbuffer in it. in wp, i found meshVertices is a array from meshvertexbuffer through the function GetData, but in android GetData is not working, and gets error : Vertex buffers are write-only on OpenGL ES

i want to write a function to read data from vertexbuffer, but i don't found the structure in wp .

i want a answer , how to transer the VertexBuffer from a model to array？

Comment: Have you looked at this, http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object?

Comment: thanks fassetar, i read that page, i think i will write my own getdata function to get vbo data. is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this question which I think will help explain your's.

Question:[Opengl Vertex Array Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12869025/2444126)

**Update**

This might also prove to be helpful: [Vertex Specification Best Practices](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification_Best_Practices#Formatting_VBO_Data).